# window.open adds page after a url not replace it

Tags: javascript, html

`var urladdress = 'autopage`

I used `window.open(urladdress, "_self");` to load a new url but it was adding urladdress to existing address within the browser i.e.
current url within the browser is https://currenturl.com/currentpage/ I want to load a new page autopage so expected url is https://currenturl.com/autopage/
but using `window.open(urladdress, "_self");` leads to https://currenturl.com/currentpage/autopage/.

Please how can i achieve that

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from your "urladdress" variable.
Writing your link like this "link" will just add it to the current active path.
If you want to always end up in "www.example.com/link" just add an "/" before your path ("/autopage" in your example).